# Bit cost per pixel of PNG file

Tags: vb.net

In the PNG file format [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Compression) I saw this conversion of an image to a representation of the cost of bits per pixel (red=expensive, blue=cheap).

[image: Conversion]

I was wondering if it is doable to program that kind of converter.

At the moment I don't know where to look up information about that so I decided to ask here with the little VB.NET code that I have made:

```
Dim MyBitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(filename:="C:\Original.png")
Dim MyBinaryReader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path:="C:\Original.png"))
Dim MyBytes() As Byte = MyBinaryReader.ReadBytes(count:=Convert.ToInt32(File.OpenRead(path:="C:\Original.png").Length))
Dim MyString As String = ""
For Each MyByte As Byte In MyBytes
    MyString = MyString & Convert.ToString(value:=MyByte, toBase:=2).PadLeft(totalWidth:=8, paddingChar:="0"c)
Next
Debug.WriteLine(MyString)
'For MyHeight As Integer = 0 To MyBitmap.Height - 1
'    For MyHeight As Integer = 0 To MyBitmap.Height - 1
'        MyBitmap.SetPixel(x:=MyWidth, y:=MyHeight, color:=MyBitmap.GetPixel(x:=MyWidth, y:=MyHeight))
'    Next
'Next
'MyBitmap.Save(filename:="C:\New.png")
```

Comment: You would have to look at the raw pixel data and interpret the deflate compression format.  Nothing in vb.net or the framework to help you do that, the codec is written in the C language.

Comment: @HansPassant So its possible but not doable since I would have to understand a lot of the compression algorithm right?

Comment: @user7393973 exactly, the blue is just more compressed data. You'll need to open the image, get the bytes and see which pixel is more compressed than others.

Comment: @the_lotus I edited the code to read the file as a string of bits in case someone knows how to read them.

Comment: The [RFC 1951](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1951) should have all or most of the information on how to decode the bits but it's hard to actually understand and write the algorithm that can manage so many different compressed ways that the file can have.